# RealmDb : Clean architecture in Android

Tags: android, realm, clean-architecture

I am evaluating RealmDb, I feel RealmDb is tightly coupled with model layer. Which makes me feel if tomorrow I need to replace with some other local database than it will be a huge refactoring effort.
My question is how to achieve clean architecture with RealmDB? Any examples I can follow?

Answer (score 2):

Realm just makes it easier to re-use your database models as your view models if you want. But there is nothing stopping you having data layer entities and view layer entities and then doing the mapping on the boundaries.

E.g.

```
// Data layer
public class FooEntity extends RealmObject {

  // Realm fields and methods... 

  public static FooEntity fromViewModel(FooViewModel viewModel) {
    // Convert to entity
  }

  public static FooViewModel toViewModel(FooEntity entity) {
    // Convert to view model
  }


}

// View layer
public class FooViewModel {
  // Standard POJO used by the View layer
}
```

In many cases that is most likely overkill, but it will give you the seperation you want.

Comment: I am not sure if my understanding is correct, does that mean my data layer entities need to inherit from RealmObject?

Comment: Yes, since it would be your data layer what would be responsible for saving and storing Realm data

Comment: With that approach, what is best practice **updating** an already persisted model? Can I just call `fromViewModel` and perform a `realm.insert(fooEntity)`? Or do I need to perform first a `findById` and than call the setters on the retrieved object inside a transaction?

Comment: It depends entirely on your use case. You can either do `realm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(DBModel.from(viewModel))` or make the view layer create small action messages that the model layer will translate into only calling setters on a few fields. Personally, I like smaller actions as it makes the intent of the code more readable and allows you to merge changes from the UI and network, but it is also is slightly more work.

Comment: @einsA you'd have to call `realm.insertOrUpdate(fooEntity)`, `insert()` wouldn't work for update.

Answer (score 2):

There are different architectures where the main objective is to isolate the domain of our application of the frameworks as Clean Architecture, Onion Architecture, Hexagonal Architecture.

To achieve this isolation, the implementation details are hidden as the data layer. A boundary or port is defined in the domain layer defining how the stored data is accessed but without knowing how they are stored, the repository pattern is usually used to implement this architecture requirement.

With these requirements we will generally have a persistence model and a differentiated domain entities. Persistence models can and should be coupled to the framework we are using for example Realm.

I leave a diagram where you can better understand it graphically.

[image: Clean Architecture]